# Jquery posts not working with flask-restless, where curl -H posts are

Tags: jquery, flask

I have a flask application installed, running the flask-restless API
the following command executes successfully:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.15000/api/menu -d '{"name":"Hello Data"}'
```

but when attempting to do the same thing with javascript, it fails.  I've traced it down to the problem line of code in the flask-restless api, and added a debug statement that prints out request.data, since it relies on that.

The jquery query that got closest to working was:

```
$.ajax({
url:'api/menu', 
type:"POST",

contentType:"binary/octet-stream",

data:{name:'foo'}});
```

for which request.data gets assigned "name=foo", when it should be {'name':'foo'}

I have tried every permutation of (contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json")
for content type application/json, binary/octet-stream, 
an in all other cases, data is just blank, and request.form has an immutable dict.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Oops - the data - was not being sent as json
you've got to do

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:5000/api/menu', 
    type:"POST",

    contentType:"binary/octet-stream",
    host:"localhost",
    data:JSON.stringify({"name":"foo"})});
```

note JSON.stringify !!!